# In responsive web design, how to decide break points for nested columns?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, breakpoints

Suppose I have 2 columns, say c1 and c2, both with width:50%. c1 has 2 nested columns, c1-1 and c1-2, with widths 30% and 70% respectively.

Suppose the content of c1-1 displays best when it is at least 150px width, that is, when this screen size >= 1000px. What would you do in such a situation, when nested columns need to break before the parent?

Can I set a break point at max-width:1000px, and set c1-1 and c1-2 to have width: 100%, then at a later break point, when c1 and c2 becomes width:100%, I reset c1-1 and c1-2 to have width 30% and 70% ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, I think you should approach this from the point of view of how do you want the page content to be displayed at viewports less than 1000px.

The approach you mention would give:

| --- C1-1 --- | | --- C2-1 --- |
| --- C1-2 --- | | --- C2-2 --- |

Another option would be at viewports < 1000px, define C1 and C2 as full width and the nested columns as 30% and 70%, ie

| - C1-1 - | | ----- C1-2 ------|
| - C2-1 - | | ----- C2-2 ------|

It doesn't look like a big difference here, but it could be important with real life data.

For example, presumably the C1-2 content is relatively important. In the first example though,  it could be pushed well down the page. Also the second method will keep the C1 and C2 content grouped together visually.

Good luck!